# Error when running nohup in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sass, nohup

My bash/nohup experience is very limited, so I might be making a basic mistake.

I'm launching a background file monitor. (In case it matters, Sass is a CSS preprocessor that can monitor source files and automatically compile them into CSS when it detects changes.)

When I enter this at a shell prompt, it launches the Sass file monitor perfectly:

```
nohup sass --watch /data/sass/:/data/css/ > /var/log/sass.out 2> /var/log/sass.err &
```

But when I put it in a script like this (a simplified sample script for debugging):

```
COMMAND="[exactly the same command as above]"
echo `$COMMAND`
```

I get this error:

```
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - > Use --trace for backtrace. >>> 
Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
```

The same thing happens if I specify the full path /usr/bin/local/sass. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run a complex command (e.g. with redirection) via:

```
echo `$COMMAND`
```

You can only really do this if you are running a simple binary or script. 
Your `$COMMAND` needs to be expanded properly before executing, so you need to run:

```
echo `eval $COMMAND`
```

Comment: This will work for redirection, but will not work if any arguments contain spaces

Comment: What do you mean? This works for me: `cmd="echo 'hi, here are spaces' > /tmp/test_eval"; eval $cmd; cat /tmp/test_eval` => hi, here are spaces

Comment: Awesome. It works exactly as intended now. Thanks for the quick response.